# how to use 'in' operator in infinispan query with parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, infinispan

I am trying to query my infinispan cache (version 12.1.7) using 'in' like so:

```java
Query<Foo> query = qf.create("from com.test.app.Foo where id in :ids")
query.setParameter("ids", idsArrayList) // idsArrayList is an array of string ids
```

but when i run my application i get an error saying ':' is not allowed.

I also tried using `(:ids)` like so:

```java
Query<Foo> query = qf.create("from com.test.app.Foo where id in (:ids)")
```

but now the error is `java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable`.

I can't find any information about this beside the documentation itself but it is not very allaborated so I would love some help.

Comment: Seems to me, that usage of collections isn't supported there. There is no `setParameterList` method nor does the method throwing the exception - `ConstantValueExpr.getConstantValueAs` - cover collections at all. So the best thing I can think of for now is converting your arrayList into a string and inject it into the query directly. Of course, in JPA, this would be regarded a smell, but if there's no other choice...

Comment: Yes this is bad practice but I guess it is the only option. Thank you

Comment: When I try to convert a list of Integers to string with commas, there is NumberFromatException. Is there anyway to use ‘in’ on list of values that are not Strings?